# sql datatype rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having the below query.

```
declare
@a NUMERIC(20,4)
set @a=24900*0.3333333333
select @a
```

I am expecting `8299.999999` but it gives `8300.00`. Can some body help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is rounded as you have only 4 decimals at your disposal. Use

```
set @a = round(24900*0.3333333333, 4, 1)
```

This will not round but truncate the result.

I do not know if that is what you want, because a value like `0.12346` will be truncated to `0.1234` and not rounded to `0.1235`.

Answer (score 0):

you may want this or something like this:

```
declare @a NUMERIC(20,6)
set @a=cast(24900 as numeric(20,6))*cast(0.3333333333 as numeric(20,10))
select @a
```

Comment: This works in this particular case, but the particular issue can still occur.  The `ROUND` solutions proposed below are better options.

Comment: Thx deepak and Andrew I agree need just truncate without rounding.